# How can i redirect unwanted output on bash login over ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, centos

I've got a script, that will use ssh to login to another machine and run a script there. My local script will redirect all the output to a file. It works fine in most cases, but on certain remote machines, i am capturing output that i don't want, and it looks like it's coming from stderr. Maybe because of the way bash is processing entries in its start-up files, but this is just speculation.

Here is an example of some unwanted lines that end up in my file.

`which: no node in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin)`

`stty: standard input: Invalid argument`

My current method is to just strip the predictable output that i don't want, but it feels like bad practice.

How can i capture output from only my script?

Here's the line that runs the remote script.

`ssh -p 22 -tq user@centos-server "/path/to/script.sh" > capture`

The ssh uses authorized_keys.

Edit: In the meantime, i'm going to work on directing the output from my script on machine B to a file and then copying it to A via scp and deleting it on B. But i would really like to be able to suppress the output completely, because when i run the script on machine A, it makes the output difficult to read.

Comment: You should probably fix the script. If `which` is just being used to detect if `node` is available, you can redirect its standard error in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

To build on your comment on Raman's answer. Have you tried supressing `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` as shown below?

`ssh -p 22 -tq user@centos-server "bash --norc --noprofile /path/to/script.sh" > capture`

If rc-files is the problem on some servers you should try and fix the broken rc-files instead of your script/invocation since it'll affect all (non-interactive) logins.

Try running `ssh user@host 'grep -ls "which node" .*'` on all your servers to find if they have "which node" in any dotfiles as indicated by your error message.

Another thing to look out for is your shebang. You tag this as `bash` and write CentOS but on a Debian/Ubuntu server `#!/bin/sh` gives you **dash** instead of (sh-compatible) **bash**.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but i still get the error. `grep -ls "which node" .*` only shows the history file. Hmm, the error always comes up when i ssh in, but once i'm in the server if i just run `bash` it no longer occurs. My shebangs are all `#!/bin/bash`. I appreciate the help. Its a little out of scope for me to do upkeep on all of the remote machines, but i'm looking at some other solutions to try. I really appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can redirect stdout (2) to /dev/null and redirect the rest to the log fole as follows:

```
ssh -p 22 -tq user@centos-server bash -c "/path/to/script.sh" 2>/dev/null >> capture
```

Comment: I still get my error with this. ssh itself isn't giving me any output, i think it's the bash shell that i'm logging into.

Comment: Try adding bash -c as in the amended solution.